# Gulp 4 watch gulp.series only run one time

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I changed from Gulp 3 to Gulp 4, but I can't get it to work.

When I run `gulp` and save a js or scss file it creates a new file successfully. If I save a again nothing happends. My guess is that I don't understand how `gulp.series` works. It only run ones.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var minifyJS = require('gulp-minify');

gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src([
        'assets/css/src/tinyFileTree.scss'
    ])
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/dist'))
    .pipe(rename('tinyFileTree.min.scss'))
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/dist'))
});

// JS
gulp.task('js', function() {
  gulp.src([
    'assets/js/src/tinyFileTree.js'
    ])
    .pipe(minifyJS({
      ext:{
        min:'.min.js'
      },
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) { gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString()); })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/dist'))
});

// Default
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/css/src/tinyFileTree.scss', gulp.series('css'));
    gulp.watch('assets/js/src/tinyFileTree.js', gulp.series('js'));
});
```

Comment: First step: add return statements to your tasks ala "return gulp.src…………." and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a complete rewrite that can be found here: https://github.com/jenstornell/gulpfile-style-script.

You can also see it here. Hope it helps someone.

```
let gulp = require("gulp");
let sass = require("gulp-sass");
let autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
let concat = require("gulp-concat");
let uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
let csso = require('gulp-csso');
let rename = require('gulp-rename');

var css = {
  src: 'assets/css/src/**/*.scss',
  dest: 'assets/css/dist',
  filename: 'style.scss'
};

var js = {
  src: 'assets/js/src/**/*.js',
  dest: 'assets/js/dist',
  filename: 'script.js'
};

function style() {
  return (
    gulp
      .src(css.src)
      .pipe(concat(css.filename))
      .pipe(sass())
      .on("error", sass.logError)
      .pipe(autoprefixer())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(css.dest))
      .pipe(csso())
      .pipe(rename({extname: '.min.css'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(css.dest))
  );
}

function script() {
  return (
    gulp
      .src(js.src)
      .pipe(concat(js.filename))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(js.dest))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(rename({extname: '.min.js'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(js.dest))
  );
}

function watch(){
  gulp.watch(css.src, style);
  gulp.watch(js.src, script);
}

exports.css = style;
exports.js = script;
exports.default = watch;
```

Comment: I see you added return statements - without them those tasks will only run once.

Comment: @Mark I see. It looks like you was right all along then. Thanks! =) I needed to mess around a while before I got the hang of it. And my code looks much more readable now.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to return an gulp instance. You can just follow the [signature](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch#signature) used on the gulp watch docs. The function expects a callback function with one argument and you need to execute that argument at the end of your task. It took me a couple hours to figure out this issue but here it is.

notice the cb();

```
gulp.task('css', function(cb) {
    gulp.src([
        'assets/css/src/tinyFileTree.scss'
    ])
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/dist'))
    .pipe(rename('tinyFileTree.min.scss'))
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/dist'));

    cb();
});
```